# How to show Dialogue in fragment | Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

Using `fragment` in  my activity , i want to show a `dialogue` On `ItemLongClickListener` of `viewlist`. I have tried a few codes but failed. Is there anyway to do it?

**`code`**

```
    listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
     public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v,int index, long arg3) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"thul thuk!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
              //show-dialogue here
           return false;
                }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

**custom_dialog.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
     </LinearLayout>
```

**Java**

```
 listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
 public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v,int index, long arg3) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"thul thuk!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
          Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
           dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
           dialog.setTitle("Custom Dialog");
           dialog.show();  
       return false;
            }
});
```

**EDIT**

You can use **[Context Menu](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2013/06/09/display-context-menu-fragment/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public void showPopup(View anchorView) {

        View popupView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.popup_layout, null);

        popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, 
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);


        Button proceed = (Button)popupView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button cancel = (Button)popupView.findViewById(R.id.button2);

        cb = (CheckBox)popupView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1); 

        proceed.setOnClickListener(onProceed); 
        cancel.setOnClickListener(onCan); 

        popupWindow.setFocusable(true);


        popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable());

        int location[] = new int[2];


        anchorView.getLocationOnScreen(location);

        popupWindow.showAtLocation(anchorView, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, 
                location[0], location[1] + anchorView.getHeight());

    }
```

The above will result in a popup, just beneath the view clicked.

popup_layout is the XML layout file which will be inflated.